# How do i texture paint specfic faces

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

So im using blender 2.79 and im bit of a new to using it so here is what im trying to do
[image]

so i want to know how do i texture like a specfic face like on this image like i color the selected face of an object instead of the tool interfering with the other faces i couldnot find any ways or tutorials online im not sure if im even searching correctly

Comment: Are you talking about this? -- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/materials/assigning_a_material.html

Comment: almost like it @ChristopherBennett but using the texture paint so i get the texture i made in a png file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate the *Paint Mask* option and select the faces you want to preserve with the classical select tools + <kbd>Shift</kbd>, or select the faces in *Edit* mode and switch back to *Texture Paint* mode and they will stay selected. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to invert the selection:

[image]

In 2.79, it's called *Face Selection Masking* and use the classical selection shortcuts:

[image]

Comment: im currently using 2.79 as i said in the beginning so selecting edges arenot saved in the texture paint

Comment: oh alright thanks for the help